# Only the first stored procedure in foreach loop will work, but an inline query will? C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to insert a few rows of data to a table using a `foreach` loop, when I write inline SQL it seems to work fine;

```
connection.Open();

foreach (Bet bet in bets)
{
    string insertQuery = "insert into BetTbl (FixtureId,BetTime,UserName,PlayerId) values (@FixtureId, @BetTime, @UserName, @PlayerId)";

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, connection);

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FixtureId", bet.FixtureId);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BetTime", bet.BetTime);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", bet.User);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PlayerId", bet.PlayerId);

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

bets.Clear();
connection.Close();
```

But when I try to use a stored procedure I get an error;

> Procedure or function InsertBets has too many arguments specified

Here is the code:

```
connection.Open();

foreach (Bet bet in bets)
{
    command.Connection = connection;
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    command.CommandText = "InsertBets";

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FixtureId", bet.FixtureId);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BetTime", bet.BetTime);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", bet.User);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PlayerId", bet.PlayerId);

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

bets.Clear();
connection.Close();
```

And here is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertBets]
    @FixtureId  VARCHAR(50),
    @BetTime    VARCHAR(25),
    @UserName   NVARCHAR(20),
    @PlayerId   VARCHAR(25)
AS
    INSERT INTO dbo.BetTbl (FixtureId, BetTime, UserName, PlayerId)
    VALUES (@FixtureId, @BetTime, @UserName, @PlayerId)
```

Although it works using inline SQL, I can't figure out why it won't work using a stored procedure, can anyone tell me why?  Thanks

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first code sample a new `SqlCommand` is created in every iteration:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, connection);
```

In the 2nd one, all iterations modify the same command, adding more and more parameters. Only the first call will have the correct number of parameters, the next ones have too many.

Add the parameters before the loop without values, then in the loop set the values and execute the command

```
command.Connection = connection;
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.CommandText = "InsertBets";

command.Parameters.Add("@FixtureId", SqlDbType.Int);
// add the other paramters

foreach (Bet bet in bets)
{
    command.Parameters["@FixtureId"].Value = bet.FixtureId;
    // set the other parameters
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding parameters to the command variable every time you loop. You loop the first time and add parameters with

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue
```

and then you loop again the second time and add parameters with

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue
```

the problem is, the previous parameters are still there. you have to clear the parameters or re-instantiate the variable from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is (probably) in the part you're not showing -> where and how `command` is defined and initialized.

Since you're using `AddWithValue()` inside your `foreach` loop, you're adding value fields with each iteration, so the first iteration has 4 fields, the second has 8, then 12 and so on.

Instead, add the field once when you initialized `command`, then only set the values inside your `foreach` loop.

---

As an aside, `AddWithValue()` is often considered a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

try changing your coding style

```
 cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FixtureId", bet.FixtureId));
```

I also believe you need to create command in the loop every time instead of at outside of loop

Comment: Or better yet - to this, **explicitly** stating the **type** (and possibly length) of the parameter: `cmd.Parameters.Add("@FixtureId", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = bet.FixtureId;`. The constructor you're using with the parameter name and just the value is **deprecated**

Answer (score 0):

You're calling command.Parameters.AddWithValue and adding more values everytime it loops. Either Clear() the Parameters each loop, or initialize a new instance of Command.